# Postgresql: create role, schema and change ownership but not as superuser

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgresql-9.4, users

I need to create various schema in a database and give ownership of these to specific users. I want to do this in a script, and I rather not be the postgres user or a superuser.
My user pat has createdb and createrole privileges.

```
pat=> create role toto with login password 'pass';  
pat=> create schema toto;
pat=> alter schema toto owner to toto;
ERROR:  must be member of role "toto"
```

Is there a way to do this without being postgres or superuser ? or should I give pat superuser privileges while running the scripts and drop it after? What is the best procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterschema.html),

> You must own the schema to use ALTER SCHEMA. To rename a schema you must also have the CREATE privilege for the database. To alter the owner, you must also be a direct or indirect member of the new owning role, [...]

So in your case, you either need to be superuser or be a member of the role you are transferring the ownership to.

Ultimately, while I applaud your efforts, you're going to have a hard time managing this without some superuser use.  So I'd focus on locking down the superuser use, maybe wrap the steps in a few security-definer functions.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I understood, I was hoping I had missed something in the docs. Yes I must secure the "pat" account so that even if hacked, the scripts are not run easily. already it has a postgres password , I must add something in the scripts also then.

Answer (score 0):

> should I give pat superuser privileges while running the scripts and drop it after? What is the best procedure?

The best practice, or the way I would do this is simply to [create the schema and assign it to the user using `AUTHORIZATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createschema.html)

I would probably do it like this..

```
sudo -u postgres psql <<EOF
  CREATE USER toto WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'pass';
  CREATE SCHEMA toto AUTHORIZATION toto;
EOF
```

Comment: not sure this is better than being the postgres superuser. in this case, i must have the sudo privileges, and if I want to run the cmd from a script, I have the same problem with the password .

Comment: @Pat070 that is doing it as the PostgreSQL superuser. I just keep my postgres superuser locked, as is best practices. And, sudo doesn't have to require a password, you can set that up in `sudoers` see `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: sure but I feel less safe with sudo without password. you would say that once somebody got my password, sudoers or not ... I have to think a about that